# How do you extract scripts in GitLab and install the module in Python?

Tags: python, installation, module, download, gitlab

I'm new to python (and to programming in general). I have no experience with GitLab, but I've been given a directory in GitLab that should have all the scripts I need to install all the python modules I need, but I'm not sure how to do that. I can download the directory as tar.gz or tar.bz2 or tar, but I'm not familiar with these types of files and not sure which I need or what to do with it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have git installed, you can clone the project to your computer with the command:
`git clone <url>`
You can get the URL from GitLab, there are for HTTP or ssh.
After it, if the project has a `requirenment.txt` file, you can install all requirements with: `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  Else, you will need to install all libraries with pip or conda.

Comment: Thanks. I got the URL from GitLab, but the command
git clone <url>
does not seem to work for me. I get an invalid syntax error...